# entryComponents is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a problem when using ng-bootstrap modal in angular 6.

First, I have 2 module:

`AppModule` and `ComponentModule`

Here is `ComponentModule`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ComponentRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
   CategoryComponent,
   CourseComponent,
   ModalComponent,
   CategoryModalComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [CategoryModalComponent],
})
export class ComponentModule { }
```

`ComponentModule` is where I put component that will be displayed after I logged in.

In a `ComponentModule`, I have a Course component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  template: '<app-modal></app-modal>',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.scss']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is `ModalComponent` in the same module:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: '<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(CategoryModalComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-modal',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./category-modal.component.scss']
})
export class CategoryModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I expect that when I click button in `ModalComponent`, I will show a modal that its content is in `CategoryModalComponent`. But it showed me an error:

```
ModalComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: No component factory found for CategoryModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3256)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3291)
    at NgbModalStack.push../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js.NgbModalStack._createFromComponent (ng-bootstrap.js:7643)
    at NgbModalStack.push../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js.NgbModalStack._getContentRef (ng-bootstrap.js:7581)
    at NgbModalStack.push../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js.NgbModalStack.open (ng-bootstrap.js:7444)
```

[image]

According the error, I added it in `ComponentModule` but it's not working.

Could you please give any advice to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add NgbModalModule or NgbModule to your ComponentModule.

There is no ngb modules in your Components module.

nb: Tried and worked in your case.

```
 import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
    ...
    NgbModalModule
   ],
   ...
 })
 export class ComponentModule { }
```

Comment: But wait, I've imported NgbModalModule in the ModalComponent. Why should I import the module in the ComponentModule?

Comment: ComponentModule is the parent module of all your Modal component and catagory component.and we import modules to the parent module  so we can use it in all components in that module. why you import module in the component?

Comment: Because when I press Alt + Enter, WebStorm geenerated import statement for the component automatically :)))))

Answer (score 1):

You should add 'CategoryModalComponent' as the declarations & entryComponent in Module.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxgjqrndxkoq

Comment: Adding it to the declarations, even though it was already added to entryComponents was key for me